# AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate not calling back the AVplayer

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer

I am trying to set up a progressive video download to stream from a server URL. I am able to call the AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate, first with the information request, then with the data request, which gets the first 1000 bytes of data. However, the delegate never calls back and starts the player. I checked the data byte by byte and it is correct.

```
-(void)videoCallingMethod {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"fakeurl://mypath.com/moviefile.mp4"];

    dispatch_queue_t serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.meels.queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
        dispatch_async(serialQueue, ^{
            _asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:nil];    
            [_asset.resourceLoader setDelegate:self queue:serialQueue];

            _playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:_asset];
            _player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:_playerItem]; // This will call the delegate        

            _playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:_player];
            [_playerLayer setFrame:self.view.frame];
            [self.view.layer addSublayer:_playerLayer];
            [_player play];
    });
}

- (BOOL)resourceLoader:(AVAssetResourceLoader *)resourceLoader shouldWaitForLoadingOfRequestedResource:(AVAssetResourceLoadingRequest *)loadingRequest {

    BOOL returnValue = FALSE;
    if(loadingRequest.contentInformationRequest) {

        loadingRequest.contentInformationRequest.contentType = @"public.mpeg-4";  // "public.mpeg-4" "kUTTypeMPEG4"
        loadingRequest.contentInformationRequest.contentLength = 1000;
        loadingRequest.contentInformationRequest.byteRangeAccessSupported = YES;

        NSLog(@"contentInformationRequest loadingRequest %@", loadingRequest);
        [loadingRequest finishLoading]; // This will trigger the data request   
        returnValue = TRUE;

    } else if(loadingRequest.dataRequest) {
        NSLog(@"It's a dataRequest");

        // Here the url custom scheme is removed and the url changed back to http to point to the exact url location where my file is
        NSURLComponents *urlComponents = [NSURLComponents componentsWithURL:loadingRequest.request.URL resolvingAgainstBaseURL:NO];
        urlComponents.scheme = @"http";
        NSMutableURLRequest *mutableLoadingRequest = [loadingRequest.request mutableCopy];
        [mutableLoadingRequest setURL:urlComponents.URL];

        NSURLSession *session = [[NSURLSession alloc] init];
        NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config delegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];
        [[session dataTaskWithRequest:mutableLoadingRequest completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            NSLog(@"Session block complete with error %@", error);

            if (error != nil) {
                NSLog(@"Error, %@", error);
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Response: %@",response); // status code: 206
                NSLog(@"data: %@",data);         // The data is correct
                if (data != nil) {
                    NSLog(@"Completing the request: %@", loadingRequest.dataRequest);
                    [loadingRequest.dataRequest respondWithData:data];
                    [loadingRequest finishLoading];     
                }
            }  
      }] resume];

      returnValue = TRUE;
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

When I call `[loadingRequest finishLoading];` I am expecting the delegate to pass the data back to the `resourceLoader`, and the player to start playing However that does not happen.

The delegate complete without any error. I inspected the data and it is correct. The server responds with a status code 206. I tried using MIME and UTI in different formats. It does not affect the response. Also, if I disable the delegate and reinstate the http url scheme, the video loads and plays fine. So there is nothing wrong with the file itself.